# VirtualQueryEx with BaseAddres starting at 0

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to retain info about all the regions in my process. To do so I'm using VirtualQueryEx. Where is my main`

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mem;
    unsigned long addr = 0;

    while (VirtualQueryEx(GetCurrentProcess(), (PVOID)addr, &mem, sizeof(mem))) {
        addr = (unsigned long)mem.BaseAddress + mem.RegionSize;
        printRegionInfo(mem);
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BAD_LENGTH)
        _tprintf(_T("--- Reading SUCESSFULL ---\n"));
    else
        _tprintf(_T("--- ERROR: Read stopped ---\n\tGETLASTERROR = %u\n"), GetLastError());

    _tprintf(_T("Prima qualquer tecla para terminar\n"));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

`:

pringRegion is just access to the struct and printing results.

In the first execution of VirtualQueryEx addr is 0 and therefore it's supposed to go to the base address of the current process but instead its always displaying mem.BaseAddress as 0 which I'm pretty sure it's correct or just not doing what I'm expecting. Also the cycle is going through so many regions that it doesn't fit in Visual Studio's console which, once again, I'm almost certain that it shouldn't do that when the only process being verified is the current one.

Does anyone know why is this happening or how to solve it?

EDIT:

When the while is over and I'm checking GetLastError it's showing always as ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when it's expected to be ERROD_BAD_LENGTH because it indicates that I reached the end of the pages for that processs.

Comment: Um, nowhere in the documentation does it say that passing zero for the address gives you the base address of the process. Passing zero means you want to query what is at address zero.

Comment: So how are you supposed to make it start in the base address of the process that you pass as the first argument and stop when there are no none left from that process?

Comment: You have to get the base address by some other means. It is not clear why you are doing this. Note that there can be things below the base address.

Comment: The point of all this is to watch how the values of the regions will change when I have some other processes running at the same time. It's for a work for my Operating System class.

Comment: Get some insight in the way VM is used with SysInternals' VMMap utility.  Let's you double-check your results.  And it tells you a lot more about what the VM allocations are used for.

Comment: Then start from zero and work your way through the address space.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this and it is rather interesting, but not incredibly surprising.  As the executable loads, it creates memory sections for itself.  Some to contain executable code, others to load global data elements, others to provide it with some starting address space for mallocs.  There are some sections to allow the executable to create vectors into other DLLs.  These are just address regions for calling external functions and not really part of your program's executable code.

Look at the mem->State fields for each of the regions - particularly for the mem->State == MEM_COMMIT regions.  They describe the accessibility of those address spaces.  Additionally, any of the regions are not really physical memory, but virtual address spaces set aside in case the program needs them.

Don't be overwhelmed by the number of regions.  All of them do not really describe new physical spaces for the application, but virtual address sets that can be used by your application.